# How many processes should I create for the multi-threads CPU in the computational intensive scenario?

Tags: python, process

I have a 32 cores and 64 threads CPU for executing a scientific computation task. How many processes should I create?
To be noted that my program is computationally intensive involved lots of matrix computations based on Numpy. Now, I use the Python default process pool to execute this task. It will create 64 processes. Will it perform better or worse than 32 processes?

Comment: Test it. There’s no single answer for these since all programs are different and use the processor differently. Some will have waiting so 64 might be good. Some don’t.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that Python is suited for multi-threading computational intensive scenarios, due to the Global Interpreter Lock ([GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). Basically, you should use multi-threading in Python only for IO-bound tasks. I'm not sure if Numpy applies since the heavy part if I recall correctly is written in C++.

If you're looking for alternatives you could use the [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) framework to distribute the work across multiple machines. I think that even if you run your code in local mode (i.e. on your machine) with 8/16 workers you could get some performance boost.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I just read on the GIL page that I linked that it doesn't apply for Numpy. I still think that this is not really the best tool you can use, since effective multi-threading programming is quite hard to get right and there are some other nuances that you can read in the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give you an answer as it will depend on your exact problem and code but potentially also of your hardware.
Basically the process for multi-processing is to split the work in X parts then distribute it to each process, let each process work and then merge each result.

Now you need to know if you can effectively split the work in 64 parts while keeping each part around the same time of work (if one process take 90% of the time and you can't split it it's useless to have more than 2 processes as you will always wait for the first one).

If you can do it and it's not taking too long to split and merge the work/results (remember that it's a supplementary work to do so it will take extra time) then it can be interesting to use more process.

It is also possible that you can speed-up your code by using less process if you pass too much time on splitting/merging the work/results (sometime the speed-up obtained by using more process can be negative).

Also you have to remember that in some architecture the memory cache can be shared among cores so it can badly affect the performances of multiprocessing.